# Titanium No "android- 10" or "android-2.3.3" in the Android SDK error

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

Whenever I try to create a new Mobile Project at Appcelerator Titanium, the following error comes.

How do I handle this?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: update your sdk (add packages and lib of android 2.3)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is explained very clearly.Have u tried installing android sdk 2.3.3 and then try

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to download android 2.3.3. Android sdk has sdk manager which can donwload under sdk directory:

```
   sdk/tools/android
```

select adnroid 2.3.3 (API 10) it will download and install in 10~20mins.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html